# Highlight label when clicked on the corresponding plot in a flot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

[image: Image_output]

I have a float graph as shown in the figure. I need to highlight a label when a  corresponding plot is clicked.

```
/*The below is my function where my HTML is defined in JavaScript*/ 

function insertlabel()
{
    placeholder.find("ticklabels").remove();
    var html=['<div class="ticklabels" style="font-size:smaller;    color:'+options.grid.color+'">'];

    function addlabels(axis,labelgenerate){
        for(var i=0;i<axis.ticks.length;++i){
            var tick=axis.ticks[i];
            if(!tick.label||tick.v<axis.min||tick,v>axis.max)
                continue;
            html.push(labelgenerate(tick,axis));
        }
    }
}

//This is the addlabel function 

addlabels(axes.yaxis,function(tick,axis){
    return '<div id="text" style=position: absolute ; some calculation +ticklabel /div>'
}


/*The jquery code is as follows.*/

$(this).click(function() {
    $('#text').each(function() {
        $(this).css('color','#C4BD97')
    });
});
```

This is the jquery code i tried but its highlighting only the last label whichever plot  is clicked. I want to highlight only the corresponding label when its series plot is  clicked.

Comment: Is this the same question, yet again (I think its the third time) as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697347/

Can you edit your previous questions instead of asking new ones?

Comment: yes sir same que but now i have provided an image as to what i want. As i dint find a solution to my problem :(

Comment: @user2029107, It is considered bad etiquette around here to ask the same question repeatedly.  If you have information to add, you should have edited the old question.  Also, please take the time to read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Your main problem is you've cut and pasted some snippets of code without any context.  Why are you replacing flot's labels with your own?  Have you investigated the `plotclick` handler?  Etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that'll highlight the y axis label of the y value of the point clicked.  I didn't bother replacing `flot's` axis labels with custom labels, as you seem to be doing (I'm not sure where you are going with all that).

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        var yVal = item.datapoint[1];
        var yAxis = plot.getAxes().yaxis;             
        for (var i = 0; i < yAxis.ticks.length; i++){
            if (yAxis.ticks[i].v == yVal){
                yCor = yAxis.p2c(yVal);                    
                $('#arrow').css({'display':'block','top':yCor});
            }
        }            
    }else{
        $('#arrow').css({'display':'none','top':yCor});
    }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7hsa/).